# Pyenv installation on Macos

Tags: python, installation, python-3.10, macos-ventura

While trying to install Python 3.10.11 on Mac Os ventura 13.3.1 this error occured

> BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.3.1 using python-build 20180424)
>
> Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/wh/km8d1kyd60g15x2xxbf29_h00000gn/T/python-build.20230428163825.18542
> Results logged to /var/folders/wh/km8d1kyd60g15x2xxbf29_h00000gn/T/python-build.20230428163825.18542.log

Last 10 log lines:

```
checking for python3.10... python3.10
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/wh/km8d1kyd60g15x2xxbf29_h00000gn/T/python-build.20230428163825.18542/Python-3.10.11':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop
```

While trying to install Python 3.10.11 on Mac Os ventura 13.3.1 this error occured